# Spatie Data Transfer Object error invalid type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, dto

I use in my laravel project composer package https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object

**Controller**:

```
$postData = PostData::fromRequest($request);
```

**PostData** class

```
class PostData extends DataTransferObject
{
    public string $id;

    public string $title;
    
    public CommentData $comment;

    public static function fromRequest(Request $request): self
    {
        return new self([
            'id' => $request->input('id'),
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'comment' => $request->input('comment'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**CommentData** class

```
class CommentData extends DataTransferObject
{
    public string $id;

    public string $postId;
    
    public string $text;

    public UserData $user;
}
```

**UserData** class

```
class UserData extends DataTransferObject
{
    public string $id;

    public string $name;
    
    public string $email;
}
```

I get error inside `CommenrData` class in this line:

```
public UserData $user;
```

**Error message**

> Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObjectError
>
> Invalid type: expected `App\DataTransferObjects\CommentData::user` to
> be of type `App\DataTransferObjects\UserData`, instead got value
> `array`, which is array.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to to set the $user attribute to an array, which is not what it was expecting. What are the full contents of the error? What file and line number are related to $user being set? What does the code responsible for that look like?

Comment: [Seems fine here.](https://phpsandbox.io/n/noisy-darkness-3mv0) Are you using the last version of the package? Are all your classes in the same namespace or using proper `use` statements?

Comment: @Jeto error is found. I've error inside `PostData` class in line with code `'comment' => $request->input('comment'),` I must define this as asoss. array instead.

Comment: @Jeto your comment helped me to solve a problem in my code. Somehow, it only works if I use the whole class path in `@var`, and it breaks, when I remove "unnecessary" qualifier and use the `use` statement instead. Probably, this is due to me using the old version of the library, namely: `v1.x-dev`, as the project I maintain is locked to PHP 7.1.